# Is there a x64 version of MsStkPrp.dll

Tags: activex, 64-bit, atl, clsid

I'm porting an ATL control to 64-bit.  The control uses the Stock Property pages (CLSID_StockFontPage, CLSID_StockColorPage) in its properties dialog.

After recompiling for x64, the Color and Font tabs are missing (because MsStkPrp.dll is 32-bit).  Is there a 64-bit version of the dll or is there a better way to implement fonts and colors in an ATL ActiveX control?

Comment: Pretty sure there is not, I certainly don't have it.  ActiveX is pretty dead technology.

Comment: Thanks.  I came to the same conclusion, on both points.

Comment: It's 2022, and believe me or not, I am looking for the 64bit MsStkPrp.dll (same reason, porting 32->64bit a hybrid C++/COM/ATL/MFC/C#/.NET/... App).
It looks like it does not exist, very sad that its source is not available either (so we could recompile).
As color and font pages are rarely used, I think I will just remove those properties from the 64bit version. Unless I could get the source or 64bit bin.

Answer (score 4):

Even the 32-bits version of msstkprp.dll isn't present in Windows 10, so I copied it from my Windows XP virtual machine (%WINDIR%\System32\msstkprp.dll) to a directory. Then you can succesfully register it by starting an Administrative Prompt, change to that directory, and type

```
regsvr32 msstkprp.dll
```