# Do I need to register any DLL to use ATL ActiveX control stock property pages?

Tags: visual-c++, activex, atl

I have created an ActiveX control in VC++ 2012 using ATL.  I would like to add a Font property and benefit from the stock property page that displays a font picker.

I have created a new control that has such a stock property using the control wizard.  I've modified my code to reflect what I need to do to add the stock property.  (I now implement `ISpecifyPropertyPages`; I have the relevant `PROP_ENTRY_TYPE` and `PROP_PAGE` entries in the property map) but when I attempt to display the property editor in the designer I get a 'Not Registered' type error.

I have ATL dynamically linked which, as I understand things, means I shouldn't need to link to any external DLL for ATL.  However, where are the stock property pages implemented?  Could it be that I don't have them, and need to register them somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are perhaps facing is that stock property pages are hosted by `MSSTKPRP.DLL` and this component is not necessarily present/installed in Windows and is readily available. I would suggest not using stock property page and implement your own to avoid the troubling dependency.

See also:

- [Is there a x64 version of MsStkPrp.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524676/is-there-a-x64-version-of-msstkprp-dll)
- [Redistributing ATL and OLE DB Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235284%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) - at the bottom